# Finding Local Subnet

Tags: networking

My machine's IP is `192.168.1.67` with subnet mask as `255.255.248.0` and broadcast address as `192.168.7.255`
while some other machine in my LAN having same subnet mask but with IP as

```
192.168.2.68, 192.168.3.69, 192.168.4.70.
```

Is there any way which can list out all these IP range in local lan with same subnet mask and/or broadcast address ?

Basically, I want to list out IP of all machines available in LAN

Comment: There are 2046 possible addresses on that subnet, ranging from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.7.254. You can write a script to ping all of them to see which ones answer.

Answer (score 2):

Broadcast ping:
`ping -b 192.168.7.255`
othwerwise use `nmap`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `nmap` with your own IP and subnetmask in [CIDR-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), (`255.255.248.0` is `/21`):

```
nmap 192.168.1.67/21
```

`nmap` then makes a ping scan on every single IP-address in that subnet. This can take some time, since there are 2048 addresses in a `/21` subnet. Press <kbd>space</kbd> during the scan to see a progress.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old program called `aggis`.  It tells me this:

> herman-pts/6:~% aggis -r 192.168.1.67/21
>
> ```
>     The "*/21" aggregate containing "192.168.1.67" is:
>
>      192.168.0/21  (2048 hosts: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.7.255 )
> ```

Unfortunately, I had to just know that 255.255.248.0 is a /21 .  It did not give me the option to use the netmask, only the CIDR.

There should be tons of "IP Address Calculators" on the web that can answer this kind of question too.